# How to get the content of an embedded MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, simulink

In my Simulink model are some embedded MATLAB functions. Is there a way to get the content (the text you see in the editor) of this blocks?

My first guess was to use find_system to get the embedded MATLAB functions and then get_param to get the content. But I dont find the needed parameter name. The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.ch/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/f23-20073.html#userdefinedfcns_lib_blkparams) didnt show up any parameter for the embedded MATLAB functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [technical solution](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1XIY8J/?solution=1-1XIY8J) on the Mathworks website.