# programmatically adding "matlab function" block to simuliink

Tags: matlab, simulink

can anyone tell me how to add the "[MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html)" block to a simulink model which I am constructing programmatically? Once I add it, I will also need to know how to modify the code, which doesn't seem to be hiding inside any of the parameters I get from `get_param(my_fcn_block,'ObjectParameters')`.

As a workaround I'm currently saving a customised block to my library and inserting this with `add_block('my_lib/my_fcn_block','my_fcn_block')`

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1XIY8J/index.html

Comment: thanks, I found the solution via a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248924/how-to-get-the-content-of-an-embedded-matlab-function). I wish the method wasn't so 'non-standard', but at least it's working.